# Correct way of freezing layers

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

I have a model `M` and I am cloning it `M.clone()`
Now, I want to freeze certain layers of `M.clone()`. When I set `requires_grad=False`, it results in this error:

`RuntimeError: you can only change requires_grad flags of leaf variables. If you want to use a computed variable in a subgraph that doesn't require differentiation use var_no_grad = var.detach().`

How to freeze the layers of `M.clone()` in that case? I want to ensure that when I backpropagate using the loss computed on a batch using `M.clone()`, I compute the gradients of `M`

A small script:

```py
model = ResNet()
optimizer = Adam(model.parameters())
cloned_model = model.clone()
for p in cloned_model.features.parameters():
     p.require_grad = False
error = loss(cloned_model(data), labels)
error.backward()
optimizer.step()
```

P.S. I am not sure if I can use `.detach()` as I don't want to break the graph. Do correct me if I am wrong.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the in-place requires_grad_ function either on a [`nn.Module`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html?highlight=requires_grad#torch.nn.Module.requires_grad_) or on a [`torch.Tensor`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.requires_grad.html?highlight=requires_grad#torch.Tensor.requires_grad) directly. Here you could do:

```
cloned_model = copy.deepcopy(model)
cloned_model.requires_grad_(False)
```

Where [`deepcopy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) is from [`copy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html).

*You should copy your optimizer as well otherwise `optimizer` will be updating `model`, not `cloned_model`... resulting in no changes at all since you are not back-propagating on `model`.*